# OpenShift/nodejs: Failed to execute: 'control start'

Tags: node.js, git, openshift

After I do `git push` I receive the following error:

```
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 57af58352d52718047000135 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/57af58352d52718047000135/nodejs
remote: #<IO:0x00000001e5a2d0>
remote: #<IO:0x00000001e5a258>
```

The previous responses to this question all say to try again, but that's not working so maybe it's something I'm doing? I'm not even sure where to start to fix this.